# suppress log10 errors for missing values in SAS

Tags: error-handling, sas

I have the following bit of code that was provided by someone to establish if a mobile number begins with a 7:

```
if int(abs(mobile_telephone1)/10**int(log10(abs(mobile_telephone1)))) ne 7
    then do .....
```

This works perfectly but if the value is missing I get large error messages and I was wondering if there is a way to suppress the error messages for this particular statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't suppress errors for a specific function (usually), but you could disable them before your datastep, then re-apply them after

```
options errors=0 ;
data xyz ;
  /* some code */
run ;
options errors=25 ;
```

But why not just do it far more simply without running the risk of any errors...

```
data xyz ;
  tel = 7123455678 ;
  chartel = put(tel,12.) ;
  if chartel =: '7' then istel = 1 ;
run ;
```

Comment: Chris, Funnily enough I had converted it from char to numeric to perform the log10, your answer solves this whole issue in a single step. The character field starts with the zero so I assume putting '=: '07' will do the trick?

Comment: The '=: '07'' seems to be working so thanks very much for this, cant believe I missed it!

Comment: You can, of course, do this without creating a new character variable: `if char(put(tel,z10.),2) = '7'` or `if put(tel,z10.) =: '07'` (it looks like you want to know if the 2nd digit is a 7?)

Answer (score 1):

To more specifically answer your question (although Chris' solution is definitely the way to go), you can use the `coalesce` function.

```
if log10(coalesce(mobile_telephone1,1)) ...
```

Coalesce returns the first nonmissing value.  In this case of course 0 is also an unacceptable result, so I use 1 as it seems harmless.

Also, a somewhat better math-based solution would be

```
if (mod(mobile_telephone1,1e10) - mod(mobile_telephone1,1e9) = 7e9) ...
```

Don't need to use log10s and such, just compare the modulos.